# Interval data structure and algorithm design

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Give a large multi MB byte file in memory, a system handles delete requests  for segments typically of the order of bytes. The system has a constraint that individual purge requests of byte segments are expensive, so that the no. of purges are a minimum.

Eg. a 5 MB file receives delete requests for offsets (1, 100), (250, 550),(1000, 1200), (400, 600), (800, 900), (1100, 1150)

Effective delete requests - (1, 100) , (250, 600), (800, 900), (1000, 1200)

The users of the system always go by the absolute byte ordering of the file. Eg. if byte 1 is deleted, the users of the system will reference the actual byte 2 as byte 2.

What data structure would you use to store these intervals such that the following operations are efficient
1. Looking up an interval 
2. Inserting a new interval  that has no overlap with existing ones
3. Inserting a new interval that has partial overlaps with existing intervals. This would involve collapsing the existing intervals with the new interval to form a single large interval. Eg. Interval cache: {(1, 100), (250, 550), (1000, 1200)} ,  new interval : (400, 700) -> 
Interval cache: {(1,100), (250, 700), (1000, 1200)}

Comment: The easy part is building a cache and keeping a few values inside of it. The hard part is choosing a caching protocol to improve the likelihood of hits. A good basic approach is to keep a few of the largest requests in the cache so that new requests are likely to hit them, which is also more memory efficient. Perhaps try to keep 1 large request per MB segment. If ram isn't costly, keep all requests in cache until they reach a specified percentage size, cache is full, or there are no more requests coming.

Comment: Also note that in the current format, this question is quite broad and invites opinions on the many possible implementations. If you're looking for specific help, please edit your question to reflect the problems you are having in your implementation, or consider asking on the [Software Engineering SE](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) which specializes in general approach and best practices.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Aaron3468, I will edit this question be more specific.